# Problema con símbolos extraños en tildes, ñ y ¿ sólo en algunas páginas

Tags: wordpress

En una web realizada en wordpress me han aparecido sólo en algunas entradas o páginas el famoso problema de los acentos, ñ, etc...

Las soluciones que he leído en algún sitio de cambiar

```
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
```

por

```
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf-8');
```

dentro del wp-config.php no funcionan, ya que al hacerlo las entradas que se ven mal pasan a verse bien, pero entonces todo el resto de la web (títulos, menús, páginas, entradas...) que estaban bien pasan a verse mal.

¿Alguna idea de cómo solucionar esto?

Edito la pregunta para aclarar que en el editor de wordpress se ve perfectamente y sin problemas, pero en el frontend aparece este problema. Comprobado con firefox y chrome, tanto en pc como en móvil.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba a añadir también la colación. En este enlace se explica bien:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php

Básicamente:

```
define( 'DB_COLLATE', 'utf8_spanish2_ci' );
```

A ver si así... lo que está claro es que en algún lugar de la base de datos de donde coge esos datos no tiene UTF-8 asignado, por eso tendrás esos problemas. Revísalo también :)

Comment: Probado y sigue igual. De hecho es como si no hubiera tocado nada, ya que sigue todo igual. Anteriormente estaba define( 'DB_COLLATE', ' ' );

Comment: Lo que me vuelve loco es que sólo pase en unas pocas entradas. ¿Qué sentido tiene?

Comment: Por lo que dices, al cambiar utf-8 por utf8 funciona y otro se estropea, entonces quiere decir que tienes que dejar como estaba eso, para que wordpress se vea bien e ir a la base de datos, donde se guarden las entradas y títulos y codificarla a UTF8 collate spanish2_ci, ya que puede que tengan general o latin. Prueba así a ver qué tal.

Comment: He encontrado una de las entradas afectadas en la tabla wp_posts pero 
en ninguno de los campos de la tabla aparece la codificación para poder cambiarla.

Comment: Lo estás viendo bajo phpmyadmin o cómo ? en phpmyadmin es bastante fácil.

Comment: He encontrado esto también:

http://snipplr.com/view/57234/

`UPDATE tabla SET campo = convert( convert(campo USING BINARY) USING utf8);` 

`ALTER TABLE tabla CHARSET = utf8;`

`ALTER DATABASE basedatos CHARSET = utf8;`

Prueba a cambiar el CHARSET de la tabla, a ver si esa se corrige.

Comment: Sí, con el phpmyadmin. Las columnas de wp_posts son ID - post_author - post_date - post_date_gmt - post_content - post_title - post_excerpt - post_status - comment_status - ping_status - post_password - post_name - to_ping - pinged - post_modified - post_modified_gmt - post_content_filtered - post_parent - guid - menu_order - post_type - post_mime_type - comment_count.  Nada de codificación o colación

Comment: Viendo la tabla wp_posts con phpmyadmin,  dentro de la sección operaciones el apartado cotejamiento estaba como utf8mb4_unicode_ci. Lo he cambiado por utf8mb4_spanish2_ci que habías comentado pero no ha cambiado nada en absoluto. Sigue el mismo problema. La entrada se ve perfecta en el backend y mal en el frontend.

Comment: Claro, si abres la tabla en el panel izquierdo te salen los campos y los tipos, cotejamiento, atributos, null, etc.
Ahí puedes cambiar el cotejamiento.
Y si no, ahí tienes los ALTER para cambiar la tabla completa o la DB completa.

Comment: Ok, borra también caché de los navegadores, que eso a veces jode muchísimo. También si es servidor propio y usas apache, reinicia apache.

Comment: Pues no funciona. Sigue todo igual a pesar del cambio y borrar caché, etc...

Comment: Prueba con otras tablas entonces... o con la DB entera, :S

Comment: Pues he visto que la DB tenia cotejamiento latin1_swedish_ci y lo he cambiado a utf8mb4_unicode_ci primero y a utf8mb4_spanish2_ci después y nada de nada.

Comment: Recuerda reiniciar apache si es necesario y borrar caché. Es raro, desde luego. Prueba ahora a intercambiar wp-config.php, a ver si así. Prueba todos esos cambios que se te ocurra, pero recuerda borrar cachés, probar diferentes navegadores, etc.

Comment: Has conseguido arreglar el problema de los caracteres de alguna forma ?

Answer (score 1):

En PHPMyAdmin cambia el cotejamiento de las tablas a utf8_general_ci:

1.- Seleccionas y abres la BBDD

2.- Vas a la pestaña "Operaciones"

3.- En cotejamiento elijes "utf8_general_ci" y le das a continuar